# WP7 ContentPresenter passing DataContext to DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

I have a data item:

```
<SampleData:Item Title="Evening News" Channel="ABC" x:Key="sampleData0" />
```

In my xaml page, I have a ContentPresenter that displays this item.

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dt1}" />
```

Here is the data template, **dt1**:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="t2">
        <Grid Background="#FF5599DD" DataContext="{StaticResource sampleData0}"  >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>              
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel}" Grid.Row="1" />             
        </Grid>         
    </DataTemplate>
```

This all works fine.  But I want to put the data template into my dictionary.xaml file, so I have to move the data context from the DataTemplate and into the ContentPresenter.

Now my ContentPresenter looks like this:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dt1}" DataContext="{StaticResource sampleData0}" />
```

And the data template looks like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="t2">
        <Grid Background="#FF5599DD">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>              
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel}" Grid.Row="1" />             
        </Grid>         
    </DataTemplate>
```

But this doesn’t work!

I have experimented with RelativeSource but no luck.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the `DataContext` on the `ContentPresenter` set the `Content` property. Like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource sampleData0}"
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dt1}"/>
```

Comment: Yep. That's it.  And if the I want to set the Content when the ContentPresenter is an item in an ItemControls, I use 'Content="{Binding}"'.  Thanks!!!